# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encriptación

Intentar descifrar un mensaje de socket en el servidor; en el cliente me funciona correctamente si cifro y descifro con el mismo método.

De este modo descifro en el servidor:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
//leemos lineas a través de la consola      
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8")); 

String keyS = "clave-compartida";
SecretKeySpec claveAES = new SecretKeySpec(keyS.getBytes(), "AES");

//objeto cipher con el algoritmo AES
Cipher cAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cAES.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,claveAES);

line = br.readLine();   
String textoDescifradoAES = new String(cAES.doFinal(line.getBytes())); 

//obtengo el texto descifrado
System.out.println("Texto descifrado: " +textoDescifradoAES);
```

Esta es la excepción que recibo:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.prepareInputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1005)
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:848)
>     at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
>     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
>     at Server.main(Server.java:52)

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837363/236345), podría ayudarte que recuperes los bytes de la línea que lees especificando Unicode de forma explícita.

```
String textoDescifradoAES = new String(cAES.doFinal(line.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Así mismo, dejar la indicación que tu configuración actual va a usar el algoritmo `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`, que no es el recomendado para una configuración segura.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, cuando añado el UNICODE_FORMAT no me lo reconoce indicandome que no puede ser resuelto como una variable, ¿Hay que importar alguna librería o algo? En cuanto a lo de la configuración gracias, es simplemente un ejercicio de clase.

Comment: perdón, mala mía trayendo info de la respuesta que cité. respuesta editada

Comment: nada gracias, sigue dando la misma excepción.

Comment: La idea es usar [este getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) en el que uno pone el nombre del Charset. El nombre es uno de los [soportados](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) y segúñ esta documentación, sería `UTF-8`. :/

Comment: gracias, lo probaré